# What is the most legal way I can obtain ∞ currency?

Tags: economy, law

Of course one way is to simply print it, but that is terribly illegal.

My question is, what would someone have to do to obtain as much currency as they please legally. Namely, you put in initial effort and (finite) starter money, and then at any time and as many times as you like, you can name a number in {0, 1, 2, 3...}* and pretty much effortless and quickly you will obtain that amount of money.

- It isn't about getting caught. He wants to do this without hiding anything. I am looking at what would be the easiest for his lawyers to defend if someone tries to sue.
- Either physical or digital will count.
- You can pick any currency you like.
- The more different currencies he can do this with the better (in case he crashes the economy of some of them.)
- The more of the currency already in circulation, the better (to make it harder to crash.)
- **Again though the major determining factor is how legal his method is. If in a court of law with all the facts, he gets sent to jail (and loses his money), you lose.**

Note: [This may be useful.](https://www.google.com/search?q=troll%20economics&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIgMP9zuL5xgIViqKACh2QEQH0&biw=1366&bih=616#imgrc=_)

---

* Okay, the sheer amount can't cause problems (besides economics) such as crushing things physically or overflowing the bank's computer digitally.

Comment: Is time travel allowed?

Comment: What do you mean by illegal? What country is it? Do you consider violating the international laws as illegal?

Comment: @HDE226868 According to physicists, not. Unfortunately, not even *literally* all the money in the world can buy magic.

Comment: @Vincent I am considering legality as not black and white, but more of a *sliding scale*. The goal is even if you comply with law enforcement, you won't get arrested. International law is probably a no-no if the country you are using the currency in recognizes it. Again though, *sliding scale of legality*.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to have an infinite amount of money, at a finite time ("quickly and effortlessly"), taking up a finite amount of space? Do you want to do this within the limitations of physics as it is currently understood? If so, the question as stated seems impossible.

Comment: @Jonah It is essentially as much money until physically or computationally it becomes a problem.

Comment: I think you might want to reword the infinite amount of money as an "arbitrarily large amount of money."  Infinity is one of those words that you really have to mean when you say, or you get into all sorts of twisted numeric arguments.

Comment: It isn't illegal to print money if you are the Central Bank...

Comment: You can write a cheque and put the symbol of infinity in it however it's up to the bank to decide the value.

Comment: I vote that this question should be moved to "finance.stackexchange.com". : )

Answer (score 7):

The only way to get infinite money is for there to be infinite money for you to get.

Exploit the [multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) theory. Move sideways between universes and con your alternate selves into lending/giving you money. Get each of them to visit two other parallel universes and do the same and  pass half their gain on to you. This is pretty much a standard [pyramid scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_scheme). There are infinite universes in the multiverse so there is no limit to the amount you (and in fact your alternate selves) can make.

Comment: A pyramid scheme that can actually continue indefinitely! +1

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to create your own form of currency (such as bitcoin) and place a back door/hidden bug in the system.  This way, you can give yourself currency at any point in time.
It would not be illegal if it was never stated that there was a finite amount of currency.  It could also be open source so users could see the possibility for the backdoor/bug putting the liability on them.  It would not be counterfeiting because the currency was never supported by the government.

Note as your amount of currency would increase, there would be infinite supply so the actual value of the currency would decrease.  If you have infinite currency, the all other finite amounts of currency would approach 0% of what you own.  This would also lead to the cost of items approaching infinity.

Comment: Actually, simply creating your own currency is sufficient, because this implies that you are print it at will legally.  Of course the problem is the same, even if you can get others to trade their currencies for yours, printing more doesn't really introduce any new value.  Zimbabwe did this.

Comment: Please note this is already happening. They're colloquially known as “scamcoins”.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can find the way to take control of one country.

Use the central bank to print money. With time, it will generate inflation after it is injected in the economy. But then, you can print more. It doesn't have to be physical it could also be numerical money. If it gets out of hand, you can declare bankrupt and create a new currency.

Comment: `you can declare bankrupt and create a new currency`.  slight nitpick, bankruptcy is not applicable here, you just create a new currency.  Lots of countries have done this lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

If you buy an arms company and a media company you can keep the public scared of supposed enemies with media propaganda and then just profit from perpetual war. Although this won't get you infinite currency, it will soon get to the point where you have so much money that having more wouldn't make a difference. So far this method has proved completely legal to the noble volunteers who've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Take one dollar, and set up a savings account in a back with as high an interest rate as possible.</strike>

A short while later, withdraw some money - the interest gained - and place it in a new account in another bank.

Repeat. After enough time, he will have plenty of bank accounts and lots of money. All thanks to just one dollar.

---

**Revised answer:**

You can't get an infinite quantity if you don't allow and other infinite quantities. so the scenario is impossible.

Comment: That requires infinite time though, which we don't have.

Comment: @PyRulez You have to have some infinite quantity to gain an infinite amount of money.

Comment: If your bank account stores your money in a number format supporting infinity (such as floating, which is common), you could set it to infinity. I just don't know a legal way to do that.

Comment: @PyRulez That's highly, highly, highly, highly illegal.

Comment: @PyRulez So according to http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/what-is-the-most-legal-way-i-can-obtain-%e2%88%9e-currency#comment54329_21312, my answer is valid?

Comment: Well, the time also becomes physically or computationally infeasible as well.

Comment: With current rates, you will die poor living a life of misery. It will take several years just to double the value. It might barely cover the inflation rate (usually 2%).

Comment: @Vincent That's why I would only put in one dollar. I'd keep everything else I had to start with. But I revised my decision.

Answer (score 0):

Not infinite but become dictator of a country. Then proceed to tax everyone out of existence whilst you build a palace and live in luxury. Make sure you control all news media. Have a private helicopter waiting in case of revolution.

Comment: That doesn't give you *infinite* money, unless you do what is described in the answer by Vincent.